# Kotlin return@forEach from nested forEach

Tags: android, kotlin, foreach, break

I want to make something like `break` in the nested forEach loop to filter data in my searchView (if data content contains any word in my search).

```
val filtered = mutableListOf<EventEntity>()

rawDataList.forEach {data ->
    text.split(' ').forEach { word ->
        if (data.content.contains(word, ignoreCase = true)) {
            filtered.add(data)
            return@forEach // **There is more than one label with such a name in this scope**
        }
    }
}
```

Does elegant solution exist in my case?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you ever encounter this error and won't be able to fix it with built in function you can apply custom labels to lambdas by adding `name@` before the block:

```
rawDataList.forEach outer@{data ->
    text.split(' ').forEach { word ->
        if (data.content.contains(word, ignoreCase = true)) {
            filtered.add(data)
            return@outer
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the `any` extension method is what you're looking for. From the javadoc:

Returns `true` if at least one element matches the given [predicate].

```
val filtered = rawDataList.filter { data ->
    text.split(' ').any { data.content.contains(it, ignoreCase = true) }
}.toMutableList()
```

Comment: `run(filtered::add)` - none of following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Comment: run function gets the string but I want to get EntityEvent reference, @raven